# Not Joining Correctly

Tags: mysql, database, join, select

I have the following query which takes a bunch of columns from a series of tables

```
SELECT Events.eventID, Events.eventName, Organisations.organisationName, Events.eventCrewSize, Events.eventGuestSize, Events.eventDate, Events.eventTime, Boat.boatName, Address.addressNo, Address.addressStreet, Address.addressStreetType, Address.addressSuburb, Address.addressPostCode, Address.addressState 
FROM Events, Organisations, Boat, Address 
WHERE Events.eventOrganisation = Organisations.organisationID AND Events.eventBoatID = Boat.boatID AND Events.eventAddressID = Address.addressID AND Events.eventDate >= CURDATE();
```

My issue is that not all events will have an organisation and instead of returning NULL for that column, it just does not include any events without an organisation.

I tried removing the organisation part from the where clause and that included null rows but it used the organisation of another event as it's value, instead of it's actual null value.

I believe this is a join issue but not sure how to structure it accordingly.

Comment: Make minimal code with unexpected behaviour & explain what you expected by referencing to a manual or textbook. Otherwise you're just asking for us to rewrite one. Comma does a cross join & where keeps rows that satisfy the condition, like inner join on. Find out how joins work. For code questions please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using left join

```
SELECT Events.eventID, Events.eventName, Organisations.organisationName, Events.eventCrewSize, Events.eventGuestSize, Events.eventDate, Events.eventTime, Boat.boatName, Address.addressNo, Address.addressStreet, Address.addressStreetType, Address.addressSuburb, Address.addressPostCode, Address.addressState 
FROM Events 
LEFT JOIN Organisations on Events.eventOrganisation = Organisations.organisationID
LEFT JOIN Boat on Events.eventBoatID = Boat.boatID
LEFT JOIN Address on Events.eventAddressID = Address.addressID
WHERE Events.eventDate >= CURDATE();
```

Don't forget to apply relation between your primary and foreign keys / normalization. You could use `NULLIF()` instead to avoid null values